# Exclude dependency imported by org.springframework.cloud

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using the below version in my pom.xml.
i want to use **spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure : 2.1.9.RELEASE** but the current version taken by maven is **2.1.2.RELEASE**.
How can i exclude this version which is imported by org.springframework.cloud.

> The managed version is 2.1.2.RELEASE The artifact is managed in
> org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-openfeign-dependencies:3.0.3

```
<dependencies>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        
    </parent>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the version as follows:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Or try setting the version as follows:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: already it doesn't work

Comment: Then try the second approach I added to my answer.